# All text in my html site is coming up as a link when I run it in localhost:5000

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a pretty simple website HTML, but when I run it in localhost, all the text that isn't within something such as the navbar, jumbotron, etc, automatically appears as a link (shows up blue, underlined, clickable and goes to the top of the page) and I can't see any reason for this. I'm working in Python/Flask/Bootstrap/Virtual Studio Code. Here is a screenshot showing what I mean:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Complete Bootstrap 4 Website Layout</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-EIHISlAOj4zgYieurP0SdoiBYfGJKkgWedPHH4jCzpCXLmzVsw1ouK59MuUtP4a1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{url_for('hello_world')}}"><img src="{{url_for('static', filename='img/logo.png')}}"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Crap</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Crud</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Cheesey Potato</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Scorpion</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>



</div>
</nav>

<!--- Image Slider -->
<div id="slides" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ul>
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='img/background.png')}}">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1 class="display-2">HELLO!</h1>
            <h3>WELCOME</h3>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg">click here</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">no click here actually</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='img/background2.png')}}">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='img/background3.png')}}">
    </div>
</div>
</div>


<!--- Jumbotron -->
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row jumbotron">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-xl-10">
        <p class="lead">This is an example site.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-2">
        <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg">Web Hosting</button></div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>


<!--- Welcome Section -->
<div class="container-fluid padding">
<div class="row welcome text-center">
    <div class="col-12">
        <h1 class="display-4">Morning!</h1>

    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="col-12">
        <p class="lead">Welcome to my website</p>
    </div>
</div>  
</div>


<!--- Three Column Section -->
<div class="container-fluid padding">
<div class="row text-center padding">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <i class="fas fa-fish fa-5x text-danger"></i>
        <h3>Fish</h3>
        <p>Browse freshwater and exotic fish</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <i class="fas fas fa-dog fa-5x"></i>
        <h3 class="text-danger">Dogs</h3>
        <p>Browse our pedigrees</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
        <i class="fas fas fa-otter fa-5x"></i>
        <h3>Otters</h3>
        <p>Check out our new range of otters</p>
    </div>
</div>
<hr class="my-4">
</div>


<!--- Two Column Section -->
<div class="container-fluid padding">
<div class="row padding">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6">
        <h2>If you build it...</h2>
        <p>According to Platts estimates and to thermal coal traders who spoke to Platts, 
            Russian producers continue to seek domination on the European market and have been 
            putting in a lot of effort to grab more market shares on the Asian markets such as South 
            Korea and Taiwan.</p>
        <p>Last year, the average free on board (FOB) coal prices for the Atlantic and Pacific markets were 
            both higher compared to 2017, which could be a big incentive for Russia to continue producing and 
            exporting more coal to seaborne destinations, according to Platts.</p>
        <p>Russia’s Energy Minister Alexander Novak briefed on Thursday President Vladimir Putin on the Russian 
            energy sector production in 2018, saying that the coal production of around 433 million tons was 
            planned to be reached in 2020. Russia plans to invest around $22.4 billion 
            (1.5 trillion Russian rubles) in its coal industry and port infrastructure, Novak told Putin.</p>       
    </div>

</div>

</div>
```

I don't have any links I haven't closed so I can't see why it'd do this. If anyone could help it'd be great, thanks. The link issue is in the 'three column' and 'two column' sections in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you forgot to close an anchor tag somewhere. On a side note,

```
<a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg">Web Hosting</button></div>
```

Did you close the `</a>` tag here?

Comment: It looks like a `div` has been incorrectly closed instead. Might also be worth pointing out that nesting a button inside an anchor doesn't really make sense (which element is supposed to receive the click?)

Comment: thanks, I did forget to close the a tag. Also thanks for letting me know about nesting the button in an a tag - I've just been following a tutorial and this is the way it was showb, no idea why.

Comment: if i just remove the a tag and leave the button nested in the div, will it work the same?

Answer (score 0):

Not an html expert but i noticed on line 84
        Web Hosting

you haven't closed 
as i said not html expert but i hope i helped :D

Answer (score 0):

There's an extra div and missing  tag. Have left comments which highlight where issues are. C

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-2">
    <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg">Web Hosting</button></div>
 // Missing an </a> tag in above line, also incorrect by html5 spec to include a button within an a tag but that's a separate problem.
</div>
 </div>
 </div> // Extra div here
```